# DatabaseFactory Class is outdated?

Tags: c#, database

I was checking DataBaseFactory documentation in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.databasefactory.aspx) site and found

> "This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained. "

Is DataBaseFactory outdated or just their documentation?

Comment: That _version_ (3.1) of the Enterprise Library is outdated - the documentation for the latest version (6.0) can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.databasefactory(v=pandp.60).aspx)

Comment: Thank you @DStanley. It seems Google shows the old documentation on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the technology and related documentation, in this case *Enterprise Library 3.1 - May 2007* is no longer in active development, but the documentation is still being made available for those that may still be using it.